Custom Keycloak first time login update password implementation in angular
I am using angular v16 and keycloak v20 so I have to implement first time login user update password feature in my app.
At present a admin creates an user with username and randomly generated password with required action update password.
So when a new user login with provided password and username from admin they are unable to generate token.
Get an error - account not fully setup.
How can I redirect the user to the updated password page and which API to call there.
When a user login they don't have any token only login credentials how they are supposed to use any rest API from keycloak.
I want that whenever user has its first time login they redirect to update password component and gets self authenticate and login successfully.
